# How to stop & start a queue in Oracle AQ

Tags: plsql, oracle-aq

What are the commands that I have to use to STOP or START an Oracle AQ Queue?

I need to STOP the queue in order to perform maintenance and analysis, and later START the queue once the analysis is complete.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You use the package [DBMS_AQADM](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_aqadm.htm#CACIJAJC).

To **STOP** a queue the command looks like this:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_AQADM.STOP_QUEUE(queue_name => 'QUEUE_NAME');
END;
```

The optional paremeter "wait" for this procedure has the following behavior:

> Specifies whether to wait for the completion of outstanding
>   transactions. TRUE means wait if there are any outstanding
>   transactions. In this state no new transactions are allowed to enqueue
>   to or dequeue from this queue. FALSE means return immediately either
>   with a success or an error.

And to **START** a queue it looks like this:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_AQADM.START_QUEUE(queue_name => 'QUEUE_NAME');
END;
```

You may have to add "SYS" as prefix for the package, depending on your permissions.

Comment: you created question, at the same moment created answer and marked it as correct?

Comment: @AlexoPo. actually, I take the time to write a question, formulate a well-written answer that works, post it on SO for you to search on google and just use it, and you dare to complain?

Comment: First link in google usually leads to oracle docs of DBMS_AQADM, so - yes, i dare.

Answer (score 3):

Often I find that I want to stop only dequeue. Then I have to use the extra options on START_QUEUE() like so

```
execute DBMS_AQADM.STOP_QUEUE (queue_name => 'schema.queue', enqueue => FALSE, dequeue => TRUE);
```